# Can you integrate internal energy to get original partition function?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

If I have the hamiltonian of the simple harmonic oscillator

$$H = \frac{p^2}{2m} + \frac{1}{2}  m \omega ^2 x^2  $$

Then it's partition function is:

$$Z = \frac{k_b T}{\hbar \omega} $$

You can get the average energy using 
$$U = \frac{\partial \ln{Z}}{\partial \beta} $$

where $\beta = k_b T $. in 1D , 
$$ U = kb * T $$

My question is, can you integrate U back up to obtain the original partition function, $Z = \frac{k_b T}{\hbar \omega} $? The closest I get is

$$\int U d\beta = \beta (T) - \beta(0) = k_b T - \hbar \omega $$

where $\hbar \omega $ is the zero point energy. The problem is that I then have to exponentiate to recover $Z$, and I get no where close to the original partition function. Any advice here?

Comment: Wow I'm an idiot. You're right, beta is 1/kbT

Comment: How are you getting that partition function?

Comment: Just integrated through the p and x coordinates from - infinity to infinity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Aaron pointed out, I miswrote $\beta$. I should have $\beta = \frac{1}{k_b T}$ , and then it works out because:

$$- \int U d\beta = -\frac{1}{\beta} d\beta = \log{\frac{1}{\beta}} - \log{0} = \log{\frac{1}{ \beta \hbar \omega}} = \log{\frac{k_b T}{\hbar \omega}}$$